# Melting a dataframe with subcolumns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-science, transpose

I have a dataframe with subcolumns at level 1:

```
A        B        C             d          
             1    2    3    1    2    3
ssd    usg   c1   c2   c3   d7   d8   d9
ssd1  usg1  c11  c22  c33  d77  d88  d99
```

C and D columns have multible sub columns which are same

I want to have columns to rows such that output should be:

[image]

Comment: What is `print (df.index)` in data?

Comment: :A                     B    C              d          
     Unnamed: 0_level_1    1    2    3    1    2    3
ssd                 usg   c1   c2   c3   d7   d8   d9
ssd1               usg1  c11  c22  c33  d77  d88  d99

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and `rename`:

```
print (df.index)
MultiIndex([( 'ssd',  'usg'),
            ('ssd1', 'usg1')],
           names=['A', 'B'])

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex([('C', '1'),
            ('C', '2'),
            ('C', '3'),
            ('d', '1'),
            ('d', '2'),
            ('d', '3')],
           )
```

---

```
df = df.stack(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_2':'new'})
print (df)
      A     B new    1    2    3
0   ssd   usg   C   c1   c2   c3
1   ssd   usg   d   d7   d8   d9
2  ssd1  usg1   C  c11  c22  c33
3  ssd1  usg1   d  d77  d88  d99
```

Comment: This was just an example . I need something generic. This way i have to write all the values in the code

Comment: @ayushgupta - yop, it is reason why is added to answer `print (df.index)` and `print (df.columns)`

Comment: @ayushgupta - it is different in your real data?

Comment: @ayushgupta - ok, so please share only first 5 values

Comment: A B C   d  
  1 2 3 1 2 3
ssd usg c1 c2 c3 d7 d8 d9
ssd1 usg1 c11 c22 c33 d77 d88 d99
ssd2 usg2 c111 c222 c333 d777 d888 d999
ssd3 usg3 c1111 c2222 c3333 d7777 d8888 d9999
xyz def asd sdf ghj wer tyu ghnb

Comment: @ayushgupta - it is first 5 values? It is index? Or columns?

Comment: can be any value . main thing is c and d columns have sub columns and they are same . (1,2,3). there are many columns like c and d this is just and example. so i just want 3 columns 1 2 and 3 and the bable rows will increase accordingly

Comment: @ayushgupta - solution working if `MultiIndex` in columns, if not, there is something wrong in data. Maybe you forget `header=[0,1]` in `read_csv`